# Mercurial: unable to use environment variables in .hgrc file

Tags: unix, mercurial, redhat, hgrc

I have two machines running Mercurial, a Solaris system and a Red Hat system.

On the Solaris system I can use environment variables in the .hgrc file, but on the Red Hat system it doesn't seem to work.

I have the following example in the .hgrc file:

```
[ui]
username = $SUDO_USER
```

but hg log shows me the following:

```
user:        $SUDO_USER
```

The variable is set and is exported:

```
$ env|grep SUDO_USER
SUDO_USER=testuser
```

The same setup works fine on the Solaris system. 
Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

Comment: what version of mercurical do you have on Red Hat? they claim it's usable since 1.4 version: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Using_environment_variables_in_hgrc_files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use environment variables with mercurial version 1.4+ according to [this page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Using_environment_variables_in_hgrc_files).

So make sure you have the most recent version installed.

Comment: Ah, I think they installed an older version. I'm running version 1.3.1 on Red Hat. Thanks